# How to dynamically load an image in Crystal 9

Tags: crystal-reports, report

Unlike crystal 11, crystal 9 has no "Graphic Location" conditional formula button. Does anyone know how to dynamically load an image from a file location in crystal 9?

edit: Still looking into this, but at the moment the only way I can see this happening is storing the images in a database.